# Selenium IDE: Verify text and click link in corresponding row in table

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am attempting to verify text in the td *NameEdit* and click the *EditTemplate* link in the corresponding row. I have attempted to find the correct xpath, but I am not sure if this is even the correct way to go about this.

The test step looks like this so far:

```
command : click
target  : //a[contains(text(${x}),'view/modify')]
value   :
```

---

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span id="NameEdit">vpxgX1</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="ShowInDropDown">No</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="OwnerName">Test</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="DateModifiedEdit">9/5/2012 4:38:25 PM</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="EditTemplate">view/modify</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String xPath="//*table/tbody/tr[last()]/a"
String txt=driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).getText().trim();
//verification
Assert.assertTrue(txt.equals("view/modify"));
//clicking:
driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath)).click();
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent to that in Selenium IDE?